# Vim search and replace digits

Tags: vim

I'm using VIM to search and replace something like so

`:0,$s/min-width:\s\d+/min-width: 61111/gc`

But it says no pattern found, even though i see very clearly there are strings like `min-width: 768px`.  If I change my vim command to

`:0,$s/min-width:\s768/min-width: 61111/gc`

THen it works.  How come the `\d` isn't being recognized?

Comment: @henices It has to be `\vmin\-width\:\s\d+`. According to the help `-` and `:` are not in the list of characters that must not have special meaning: “Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.” It does not mean they actually do have one, but they *may*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `\+` in your pattern instead of `+`.

See `:help pattern`, it says:

```
\+  Matches 1 or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible.
```

With your current pattern, you are searching for a single digit followed by a `+`.